# Subversion commit failed Merge of file: 200 OK

Tags: svn, commit

I am having the strangest problem ... every time i commit i get and error like this:

```
commit failed (details follow): MERGE of '/svn/project/trunk/web/directory/': 200 OK (http://mydomain.com)
```

that is the directory of the file i modified.

**Later Edit**
i have web dav  SVN installed and  i commit to a HTTP URL.
and there is a post commit hook doing a svn update on a directory on the same machine

Any ideas ?
thank you for your help.

Comment: Should we assume the server in question has WebDav installed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll get that error if your post-commit is failing. Try running it from the command line with the same args to make sure it works properly. I had this error a week or two ago when my python script was erroring out.

Comment: Got the same problem and it was indeed post-commit failing. Why this message is so cryptic??

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](http://ariejan.net/2007/05/21/merge-request-failed-on-pathtofile/) and [this](http://www.origo.ethz.ch/node/726) on Google... Might be helpful?

Looks like it's tied to the post-commit failing. However, it's probably actually committed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a post-commit related error.

Debug your post-commit script, generally inside your repository directory:

.../projectname/svn/hooks/post-commit

In the past I had a similar error message due to a syntax error in a post-commit email script

Flavio

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem when I had made many changes and prepared to commit to [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/). I've tried do it on command line, but failed too. I have to revert my project and split my changes to some smaller ones and commit one by one. Then it's OK.

But I doesn't know WHY.

Comment: You are right, on CodePlex it fails if you do large commits (like comming from merges). If you do smaller commits it works, it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling Proxy Server in Tortoise, under Settings/Network option.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem, and the solutions mentioned didn't solve it.
In my instance, I could commit individual files using Tortoise SVN, but all commits were failing using subclipse.
The issue was caused by my antivirus or firewall, Kaspersky. Pausing this resolved the issue.

Unfortunately, setting the svn clients as trusted does not solve the issue. I believe that this is a potential bug in the 2012 version of Kaspersky. (See [here](http://forum.kaspersky.com/lofiversion/index.php/t222048.html))

Answer (score 0):

you need to add directoty which generates error, to the subversion.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this article could help resolve this issue :
http://cntrint.blogspot.com/2009/08/subversion-autodeploy-post-commit-hook.html

Answer (score 0):

Below steps works with me

1. execute the program called 'TortoiseSVN Repository Browser' in your computer.
2. It prompts the certificate was failed, and asks me to log in and restore the certificate
3. After log in, everything was fine