# svn post-commit can't run svn update

Tags: svn

I have a post commit script that runs this command:

```
svn update '/path/to/working/dir'
```

When using Tortoise to commit from my computer to the repo on my server I get the following message:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
svn: Can't open file '/path/to/working/dir/.svn/lock': Permission denied
```

So this begs the question which user is svn running as, and what sort of permissions do I need to set on the working directory on my server?  It's also worthy of note that this supposed 'lock' file doesn't even exist.  Should SVN not simply create it?

I even 666'ed all my files and 777'ed all my directories, but it was still throwing an error, and it seems like I shouldn't have to compromise security to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Automatically updating your own working copy after committing from it? Updating some other working copy every time the repo is committed to (e.g. a live web root)? Something else?

Comment: As for why the lock file doesn't exist: the svn update command needs to create a lock file to prevent other svn clients from modifying the working copy while it's updating it, but due to permissions it is unable to create it - hence the error.

Comment: I'm not committing and updating the same working copy.  after anybody commits I want to update the working cpy on the server so that I can scp the updated files to another server.  I have found out in the meantime that svn runs as nobody.  I changed the ownership of everything within the working copy on the server to nobody.  Now when I commit I get "Commit failed (details follow): The MERGE response contains invalid XML (200 OK)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777623/subversion-commit-failed-merge-of-file-200-ok clearly means "You still have problems with post-commit hook" - prpbably due to "file not found" - hooks executed in **EMPTY ENVIRONMENT** (cleain PATH) and can't find svn executable - use it with full path

Comment: My post commit script contains the line "/usr/bin/svn update '/home/cd8597/svnwc'" when I run a commit from my system I am receiving this message: 'The MERGE response contains invalid XML (200 OK)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it working thanks to this: http://cntrint.blogspot.ca/2009/08/subversion-autodeploy-post-commit-hook.html.

I emptied the working directory and altered my post-commit script to contain this line:

```
svn checkout http://example.com/svn /home/cd8597/svnwc --non-interactive --username myusername --password **********
```

I made a trivial change to one of my files and updated svn.  That ran just fine, so then I removed the above line and replaced it with:

```
svn update /home/cd8597/svnwc --non-interactive --username myusername --password **********
```

And now all is well in my world for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should not be doing in a post-commit hook. There are numerous reasons. First, if the post-commit fails, it puts the user's working copy into an unknown state (usually doing an `svn update` will fix it). It can also take a really, really long time. This means that the user must sit there and wait for their commit to complete until your post-commit script runs.

Does this mean you can't accomplish this with a post-commit hook? No. However, you can also do an appendectomy with a Bowie knife and a bottle of whisky, but that's not the best way to do that either.

If you are trying to update a server after a commit, and then copying this to another server, may I highly recommend you consider using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins can handle this without tying up the commit process. Plus, Jenkins can log what's going on, and if things fail, notify someone via email, IM, SMS, or even Twitter.

Normally, you think of Jenkins as part of a compile process where Jenkins compiles your code after every change, but Jenkins works beautifully in environments where code isn't compiled either. I've used in in JavaScript, Python, Perl, CGI, and even PHP environments. Once you use Jenkins for this task, you will probably realize that there are other things you could do with Jenkins that you wouldn't dare do in a post-commit hook.